# Canvas keeps turning black from the bottom left up to the top right

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

On this page, https://spiritshare.org/circles.html, I'm using somewhat simple code to render some circles moving around on a gravity grid. The grid is impressed by the color of the circles as they move along it, and the weights are then drawn on the screen. But something is eating the whole universe and collapses it up to the top left corner like a reverse big bang!

I think it might be the garbage collector or possibly a math error somewhere in my code? (All of the math is right in the first page, at the bottom). Here's the relevant part, where the colors are mixed together with the circle.

```
p = (y * fullW + x) * 3;
d = Math.sqrt(xd + yd);// * 0.5; //Math.sqrt( xd + yd );
// console.log(p);
//console.log( c.r, c.g, c.b );

if( cfg.safe_colors == true ) {
    if( typeof cfg.max_color == 'undefined' ) cfg.max_color = 255;
    gravity[p + 0] = (gravity[p + 0] * cfg.color_fade + cfg.color_speed * d * c.r) & cfg.max_color;
    gravity[p + 1] = (gravity[p + 1] * cfg.color_fade + cfg.color_speed * d * c.g) & cfg.max_color;
    gravity[p + 2] = (gravity[p + 2] * cfg.color_fade + cfg.color_speed * d * c.b) & cfg.max_color;
} else if( typeof cfg.max_color != 'undefined' ) {
    gravity[p + 0] = (gravity[p + 0] * cfg.color_fade + cfg.color_speed * d * c.r);
    gravity[p + 1] = (gravity[p + 1] * cfg.color_fade + cfg.color_speed * d * c.g);
    gravity[p + 2] = (gravity[p + 2] * cfg.color_fade + cfg.color_speed * d * c.b);
    if( gravity[p] > cfg.max_color ) gravity[p] = cfg.max_color;
    if( gravity[p+1] > cfg.max_color ) gravity[p+1] = cfg.max_color;
    if( gravity[p+2] > cfg.max_color ) gravity[p+2] = cfg.max_color;
} else {
    gravity[p + 0] = (gravity[p + 0] * cfg.color_fade + cfg.color_speed * d * c.r);
    gravity[p + 1] = (gravity[p + 1] * cfg.color_fade + cfg.color_speed * d * c.g);
    gravity[p + 2] = (gravity[p + 2] * cfg.color_fade + cfg.color_speed * d * c.b);
}
```

Everything seems to be working fine, but after a little while, perhaps when some fractions start piling up or when a bug has gotten chance to get loose somewhere, the screen quickly starts piling up black pixels one by one.

It's not supposed to do that... I've updated it and it since does it less often with tighter CPU control, but still glitches when the colors get too dense and the blur (hold capital B to increase blur, warning it chews up CPU) gets too high.

Comment: It's not really working on my browser, it's about 2fps. I suggest using WebGL instead to speed this up.

Comment: just restrict the width/height and it will be fine.

Comment: I saw the effect on my end, but as George mentioned the fps is terrible. You appear to be drawing your scene pixel-by-pixel. Probably not a good idea!

Comment: just hit 'b' to disable the blur and it'll go faster. or resize the screen. but the black garbage collection still happens. webGL could be fun but I don't see these algorithms fitting well into shaders, unless I'm missing something

Comment: Include an [MCVE] inside the question itself. That is remove everything that doesn't help reproduce the issue from your code.

Comment: While I'm sure the error is small and reproducible, I'm not sure where it is.

Comment: Using Math.floor instead of parseInt to round numbers could speed things up. (still working my way through the code)

Comment: Awesome. I have done as you suggested and made a few other little fixes. It may be more difficult to reproduce the problem now, as a result.. Kaiido wasn't wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the efficiency of the code in general solves the problem, which no longer exists in the example, so I'm closing this, feel free to delete it or not, since I'll post the analysis.

I think most likely canvasrendercontext.putImageData is a threaded operation that runs out of time to complete copying the source image when too much CPU is being used by the main processing of the script.

To fix this, I added the following handler to adjust the timer interval while processing the gravity grid.

```
var gravTimeout;
function animate() {
    if( !cfg.setup ) return;
    var tn = new Date();
    gravitate();
    var tx = new Date();
    var td = tx - tn;
    var chg=false;
    if( gravTimeout < td ) { // using too much cpu.
        gravTimeout *= 1.5;
        chg=true;
    } else if( gravTimeout > td*2/3 ) { // going too slowly.
        gravTimeout /= 1.5;
        chg=true;
    }
    if(chg){
        clearInterval(gravTimer);
        gravTimer = setInterval( "animate()", gravTimeout );
        if( gravTimeout > 600 )
            console.log("gt="+gravTimeout);
    }
    //console.log(td, tn.getSeconds(), tx.getSeconds());
}
```